# '-[UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am trying to add RTCEAGLVideoView object to local video track

```
@IBOutlet var viewBG: RTCEAGLVideoView!
localVideoTrack.add(viewBG)
```

I am getting below errors

```
UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView setSize:]
PID: 609, TID: 158060, Thread name: (none), Queue name: 
com.apple.avfoundation.videodataoutput.bufferqueue
```

> '-[UIView renderFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Can any one help me on how to add video view to video track

Comment: You didn't set the class of `viewBG` in InterfaceBuilder to `RTCEAGLVideoView` instead of `UIView` (default).

Comment: I have set it to RTCAGLVideoview in Interface Builder as well. is there any good documentation about how to set videorendering in swift?

Comment: @Dutt have you resolved this?